# $(2,p)$ generation of alternating group $A_p$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, permutations, finite-groups, group-actions

Let $p>7$ be a prime, $a=(1,2,3,...,p)$, $b$ is the product of two arbitrary transpositions such as $b=(2,6)(3,5)$. I found that when $p=11,13,17,19$, the group $\langle a,b \rangle$ is always $A_p$ (use Magma), I want to know whether it is right for all prime numbers $p$. I tried the Jordan's theorem but can't find a short cycle for all situations. Can you prove it or find a counterexample for it?
Thanks a lot for any help!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The subgroup $\langle a \rangle$ of $G := \langle a,b \rangle$ is not normal in $G$, so $G$ is not solvable, and hence is doubly transitive by Burnside's Theorem.

Now by Theorem 5.4A of Dixon & Mortimer's book on Permutation Groups, if $G \ne A_p$, then the minimal degree of $G$ (i.e the smallest number of moved points of a non-identity element) is at least $\sqrt{p}$, which is greater than $4$ for $p\ge17$. So $G=A_p$.

The result about minimal degrees of 2-transitive groups is due to Jordan (1871).

Comment: Thanks, that's very helpful! And I am wondering if $b$ is the product of more disjoint transpositions, such that move more than $\sqrt{p}$ points, is there a quick way to check whether it generates $S_n$ or $A_n$?

Comment: I am not sure exactly what you are asking. Do you mean check computationally, or are you looking for theoretical results? There is a complete list of doubly transitive groups using CFSG. For a given $p$ you could check whether there are any of degree $p$ other than $A_p$ and $S_p$, and see if any of those had an element like $b$.

Comment: Actually I am trying to look for all the $(2, p)$ generators of $A_p$ and $S_p$, ie $\{(a, b) \in S_p×S_p | a^p=1, b^2=1,  \langle a,b \rangle =A_p\ or\ S_p\}$, your answer is exactly what I want, Thanks again!